# Mocha returns undefined for prototype method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm trying to run some Mocha tests against a Node module that uses the prototype pattern for creating objects. The code itself runs just fine, but the tests don't.

Here's the code I'm trying to test:

```
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs"),
  request = require("request"),
  EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter,
  util = require("util");

const FileController = function(url, path) {
  EventEmitter.call(this);

  this.url = url;
  this.path = path;
};

FileController.prototype.downloadFile = function() {
  if (this.url) {
    let file = fs.createWriteStream(this.path);

    file.on("finish", function() {
      file.close(function() {
        this.emit("downloaded");
      });
    }).on("error", function(err) {
      this.handleDownloadError(err, "file-error");
    });

    // Download the file.
    request.get(this.url)
      .on("response", function(res) {
        if (res.statusCode == 200) {
          res.pipe(file);
        } else {
          fs.unlink(this.path);
        }

        this.emit("stream", res);
      })
    .on("error", function(err) {
      this.handleDownloadError(err, "request-error");
    });
  }
};

FileController.prototype.handleDownloadError = function(err, type) {
  fs.unlink(this.path);
  this.emit(type, err);
};

util.inherits(FileController, EventEmitter);

module.exports = FileController;
```

And then here's the relevant parts of my test code where I instantiate an object:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  let url = "http://example.com/logo.png",
    path = config.downloadPath + "/cdf42c077fe6037681ae3c003550c2c5";

  fileController = new FileController(url, path);
  // Outputs 'undefined'.
  console.log(fileController.downloadFile);
});
```

When I make the call to `new FileController(url, path)`, it is not attaching the `downloadFile` method that I've attached to the prototype. Instead, trying to call that function gives me `fileController.downloadFile is not a function`.

Any thoughts as to where the problem lies?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with mocha. You need to inherit before defining your own prototype methods.

From docs

> Inherit the prototype methods from one constructor into another. The prototype of constructor **will be set to a new object** created from superConstructor.

```
util.inherits(FileController, EventEmitter);

FileController.prototype.downloadFile = function() {}
```

**UPD**
As for new versions of node. It now sets [`ctor.prototype` prototype](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v6.4.0/lib/util.js#L973) so the order doesn't matter anymore.

```
exports.inherits = function(ctor, superCtor) {

  //...Args check

  ctor.super_ = superCtor;
  Object.setPrototypeOf(ctor.prototype, superCtor.prototype);
};
```

Comment: Ah, got it. Interestingly, upgrading Node to 5.0.0 from 4.4.3 also fixes it.

Comment: Yep. I've just checked [code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v6.4.0/lib/util.js#L973). It utilizes `Object.prototype` to set ctor.prototype's prototype.